# Unable to read the data more than 4096 (1 cluster size)

Tags: freertos

I am trying to write to an OSPI Flash drive MX25LM51245GM with the FreeRTOS+FAT.

The write to the SPI flash is successful for data size of >4096.

But the read always returns 0 no matter what the size is.

```c
size_return = ff_fwrite(g_file_data, dat_len, 1, pxSourceFile);
size_return = ff_fread(g_read_buffer, dat_len, 1, pxSourceFile);
```

`g_read_buffer` always contains 0 for size >4096.

After further invstigation I found that `FF_ReadClusters` is unable to read the required data.

```c
static FF_Error_t FF_ReadClusters(FF_FILE *pxFile, uint32_t ulCount, uint8_t *buffer)
{
    uint32_t ulSectors;
    uint32_t ulSequentialClusters = 0;
    uint32_t ulItemLBA;
    FF_Error_t xError = FF_ERR_NONE;

    while (ulCount != 0)
    {
        if ((ulCount - 1) > 0)
        {
            ulSequentialClusters =
                FF_GetSequentialClusters(pxFile->pxIOManager, pxFile->ulAddrCurrentCluster, ulCount - 1, &xError);
            if (FF_isERR(xError))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

`ulSequentialClusters` is always 0.

`ff_fread` >> `FF_Read` >> `FF_ReadClusters` >> `FF_GetSequentialClusters`

Any insights?

Answer (score 4):

There is only *one* file pointer, and it points to EOF after the write call. Thus there are zero bytes to read back from.

If you wanted to read back data - which may not been written to the drive until fclose() call - you need to rewind the file pointer with f_lseek().

Have a look into the ff.c source file for details, the code is not *that* bad to read.

Comment: On closing the file with 'ff_fclose()' I get an error saying "NO MORE FILES" errno 89. The write is successful before I close the file... What could be the issue?